# How do you lock down a users access to ODBC settings in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, odbc

I was working with a users computer yesterday because they complained that an MS-Access Database they were using said that an ODBC datasource was not accessible.

I went to change the settings on the ODBC data source (which was under the systems tab) and no matter which account I logged in with I could not click the data source in question or the ‘Configuration’ button in ‘%windir%\System32\odbcad32.exe’

Is there a group policy or Windows permission that controls access to this?

If so, it seems really good for information security.

Comment: Unfortunately, this should have been migrated to SuperUser years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're referring to 32bit ODBC settings, when in fact they are 64bit? You can only edit the ODBC settings in the right editor - 64 or 32 bit. You cannot edit a 32 bit DSN setting in 64bit ODBC and vice-versa.